# Email Contents of a Page When Calling via Cron

Tags: linux, cron, cpanel

I have the following page: **example.com/test.html** with contents:

```
<b>hello world</b>
```

I call this page via cron command:

```
/usr/bin/curl -LO http://example.com/test.html
```

When the cron job executes and completes, would it be possible for it to email me the content of the page? In this example, the body of the email should contain

```
<b>hello world</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to create a shell-script that downloads the page and emails it to you, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/curl -LO http://example.com/test.html
cat test.html | mail -s "Put a subject here" address@example.com
```

and then call this script via cron.

Comment: you should be able to cut out the test.html and just pipe the curl output to mail: curl http://example.com/test.html | mail -s "Subject" address@example.com

Answer (score 0):

Write a script and call it from cron, assuming '/home/myaccount' is your home account and
'someone@somewhere.com' is your email and 'webpage' is your subject try the following

```
#!/bin/sh 

mkdir /home/myaccount/mywebdir
cd /home/myaccount/mywebdir
rm test.html

/usr/bin/curl -LO http://example.com/test.html
if [ -e test.html ]
then
    cat test.html | mail -s "webpage" someone@somewhere.com 
fi
```